# Multipart form doesn't receive fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http

I'm trying to get a file and model to my api controller and test it by sending request from fiddler. So far I have managed to receive a file using MultipartDataMediaFormatter but I can't receive fields. The some variable will be empty:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(FormData formData)
    {
        HttpFile file;
        formData.TryGetValue("fieldNameHere", out file);
        string some;
        formData.TryGetValue("code", out some);
```

The request is

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468    
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="result.pdf"    
Content-Type: application/pdf

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\mikhail.yakhyaev\Documents\result.pdf*@>

---------------------------acebdf13572468    
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code" 

asdf

---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

I've tried to make signature as `IHttpActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase fieldNameHere)` but the error is returned that request didn't hit the method.
Maybe the request itself contains error?

Answer (score 0):

I just meet the same problem, Luckily tried a lot and found out the solution.
Did you notice that the request of your model content-type is also form-data, that's the reason you cannot use FormData in api in that way.The code :

```
public IHttpActionResult Add(FormData formData)
{
   foreach(var fileValue in formData.Files){
     //do any you want
   }
   foreach(var field in formData.Fields){
     //do any you want
   }
   //may that be helpful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `encType = "multipart/form-data"` to your form tag in view?

Answer (score 0):

***success case***

```
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
                    foreach (var item in paramData)
                    {
                        content.Add(new StringContent(item.Value), item.Key);
                    }
                ......
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).